# Не могу передать параметр message в функцию

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

*Программирую бота для Telegram c библиотекой aiogram и не могу вызвать функцию send_request()*

*Код:*

```
@dispatcher.callback_query_handler()
async def callback_messages(callbackQuery: types.CallbackQuery):
    global eng_word; global eng_list_words; global keyboard; global sent_message; global bytes; global rus_word
    call = callbackQuery['data']
    button_text = ''; caption = ''
    if call == 'next_t':
        await send_request(message)  # Не могу вызвать эту функцию
    elif call == eng_word:
        caption = 'Правильно!'
        button_text = 'Дальше'
    elif call in eng_list_words != eng_word:
        caption = 'Неправильно!'
        button_text = 'Попробовать другое'

    buttons = [[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = button_text, callback_data = 'next_t')]]
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard = buttons)
    msg = f'''`{caption}` \n            *{eng_word} / {rus_word}*'''
    await sent_message.edit_caption(caption = msg, reply_markup = keyboard, parse_mode = 'MarkdownV2')
```

*Код функции send_request()*

```
async def send_request(message: types.Message):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://kreekly.com/random/') as response:
            html_code = await response.text()
            await get_text(html_code, message)
```

*Ошибка:*

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-16' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:380> exception=TypeError("callback_messages() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callbackQuery'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 388, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 225, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 273, in process_update
    return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
TypeError: callback_messages() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callbackQuery'
```

Comment: Оффтоп. Кст, `global <var>` не нужно если переменная `<var>` не создавалась глобально и не меняется в функциях. Поэтому если вы просто к ним обращаетесь, то лучше убрать `global`, а сами переменные объявить в верхнем регистре -- так визуально константы показываются

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код `send_request`